# Looping between colors in D3 Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

I'm trying to create a loop in my script to loop through an array of colors but can't seem to get it

```js
var colors = ["#bf360c","870000"]
var index1;
for (index1 = 0; index1 < Names.length; index1++) {colors};

g.append("path")
 .style("stroke", function(d,i) { return (Names[i] === "" ? "none" : colors[index1]); })
 .style("fill", function(d,i) { return (Names[i] === "" ? "none" : colors[index1]); })
```

Original code before attempting the loop

```js
var colors = ["#bf360c","870000"]

g.append("path")
 .style("stroke", function(d,i) { return (Names[i] === "" ? "none" : colors[i]); })
 .style("fill", function(d,i) { return (Names[i] === "" ? "none" : colors[i]); })
```

Any help would be greatly appeciated!

Comment: What is Names ?

Comment: The block of yor loop only has `{colors}` it’s not doing anything. What do expect to happen?

Comment: how is `g` constructed?

Comment: CodeManiac, Names is a variable containing an array of strings. e.g. var Names = ["X","Y","Z"]

@MarkMeyer, I'm trying to create a loop, that generates a color for each Name. Currently if I add 2 hex codes, it just generates 2 colors on my chart, e.g. colors only show for X & Y. I would like to create a loop to generate the first color again on Z.